# Prefetching in Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Is there a way to prefetch data in Apollo Client, like how in Relay you can start fetching data as soon as user presses down on a button (to load a new page), before the user even lifts their finger off the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use useQuery hook to fetch and storage the data in the apollo cache before you navigate to the next page. In the next page use the same hook and you will get the datainstantly from cache, that means that apollo will not make the query a second time.

If you want to make the query only when the user press a button you can use useLazyQuery hook instead to manually execute the query and wait for query resolution before navigate the user

```
function ExampleComponent() {
  const [executeQuery] = useLazyQuery(GET_BOOK);
  
  async function sendQueryAndNavigate() {
    const result = await executeQuery();
    
    yourNavigateFunction();
    
    // Then you can request your data using the query on useQuery     
    // hook or passing the result through navigation params (not 
    // recommended)
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => sendQueryAndNavigate()}>
    
    </button>
  )
}
```